# What is the best way to copy a 2d vector

Tags: c++, vector, copy, multidimensional-array

Say i have the following scenario:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> v(6, std::vector<double>(6, 0.0));
std::vector<std::vector<double>> y;

for (const std::vector<double> &p : v) {
    y.push_back(p);
}
```

This is taking a deep copy of the `v` into `y`. Is there a way to do this with `std::copy` on a `2D` vector.

```
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), y.begin())
```

will not work. For bonus points can this be extended to an `ND` vector case? This seems important to avoid the following loops which would be `N` deep:

```
...
for (const std::vector<std::vector<<double>> &p : v) {
    for (const std::vector<double> &q : p) {
        ...
```

I know that performance wise there is no difference as this is how `std::copy` is implemented. Just wondering in terms of code compactness.

Comment: `y = v;` or do it at decl-time `std::vector<std::vector<double>> y(v);`

Comment: @OMGtechy what about thread safety, preserving a large data set (say a point cloud) to do work on from a thread that gathers it but is constantly editing the point cloud as well?

Comment: Why not `auto y(v)`; ?

Comment: @billz doesn't cover cases where the vector `y` is already constructed.

Comment: @Ben regarding billz's answer, what would you want to happen? i.e. overwrite or append?

Comment: @Ben, why doesn't `std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), y.begin())` work?

Comment: @vsoftco segmentation fault.

Comment: @Ben, ohhhh because `y` has no reserved space. Use `back_inserter(y)` as the destination iterator.

Comment: @vsoftco You should add as an answer, I would upvote, it is another way to solve this issue. Although the answer would need more work to earn the bonus points i think.

Comment: @Ben, yeah inserting multiple dimensions is a bit trickier, but for 2D arrays the `back_inserter` is the way to go with `std::copy`. Added this as an answer.

Comment: @vsoftco use `back_inserter` is a slower way, it does push_back each time.

Comment: @billz agree, it is just a way to make it work with std::copy. In fact, anytime you use an algorithm you may be a bit slower than using the container's member function (if one exists). best example is find for maps.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The good practice to copy a STL container to another is : `copy construct`. Code should be faster and exception safe.

For example:

```
auto y(v);
```

If `y` is already created, use `vector::insert`

```
y.insert(y.end(), v.begin(), v.end());
```

or

```
y = v;
```

Answer (score 5):

In case `y` has no memory pre-allocated, a simple copy with `std::begin(y)` will cause undefined behaviour. For 2D-vectors, you can use `std::copy` with a `back_inserter` from `<iterator>`, like

```
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), back_inserter(y));
```

Comment: @Sajuuk Works perfectly fine, http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4afc37598dd257b9